# How to change TimePicker's timePickerMode spinner without xml?

Tags: android

I'm making a project which is used dynamic time picker. I created my time picker but it is default clock mode. Just I want to change it with spinner mode. How can I change it in my activity class?

Here is the my code:

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1_);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(timePicker, lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no setter for this property (flag in XML).
I can suggest you a workaround:

Create 2 layout files - one file containing TimePicker in `clock` mode, another - in `spinner` mode. Then you can inflate it with a `LayoutInflater`, and use them as if you've created them with a constructor.
So if you need a `clock`, then you inflate a clock. If you need a `spinner` - you inflate spinner

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    String laterTime;
```

Call this method any where you want

```
    private void openTimePicker() {
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(LabCheckOutActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            //  seheduleTimeTV.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            laterTime = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute;
            Log.e("TIME",""+laterTime);


        }
    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Sehedule Time");

    mTimePicker.show();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still is analog clock, I need spinner clock :(

Comment: There are two Types of UI of Clock Till Kitkat is different and after kitkat is different